# how to use array as value of map in avro-c

Tags: c, avro

how can i have a map with array values?

i use avro1.7.7 and my schema is like this:

```
{
    "type":"map",
    "values":{
        "type":"array",
        "items":"int"
    }
}
```

my program is like this:

main.c

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: zwlin
 *
 * Created on 2016年4月21日, 下午5:16
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <avro.h>

#define iout(i); sout("%d",i);
#define cout(c); sout("%c",c);
#define lout(l); sout("%ld",l);
#define piout(str,i); sout("%s:%d",str,i);
#define psout(str,s); sout("%s:%s",str,s);
#define pcout(str,c); sout("%s:%c",str,c);
#define plout(str,l);sout("%s,%l",str,l);

//for output

void sout(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stdout, format, args); 
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    va_end(args);
}

int main() {
    int res, i, j, k;

    avro_schema_t schema;
    avro_datum_t rec;

    //schema
    avro_schema_t int_array_schema = avro_schema_array(avro_schema_int());
    avro_schema_t int_map_schema = avro_schema_map(int_array_schema);
    avro_schema_t int_union_schema = avro_schema_union();
    avro_schema_union_append(int_union_schema, int_map_schema);
    avro_schema_union_append(int_union_schema, avro_schema_null());

    //choose schema
    //    schema = int_array_schema;
    schema = int_map_schema;
    //    schema = int_union_schema;

    //print schema
    char schemaPrintBuf [1024];
    avro_writer_t jswriter = avro_writer_memory(schemaPrintBuf, 1024);
    avro_schema_to_json(schema, jswriter);
    psout("schema", schemaPrintBuf);


    //data
    int intry[] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3};
    avro_datum_t int_array = avro_array(int_array_schema);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        avro_datum_t vt = avro_int32(intry[i]);
        res = avro_array_append_datum(int_array, vt);
        avro_datum_decref(vt);
    }
    avro_datum_t int_map = avro_map(int_map_schema);
    res = avro_map_set(int_map, "intarray", int_array);
    avro_datum_decref(int_array);
    avro_datum_t int_a_union_datum = avro_union(int_union_schema, 0, int_map);

    //choose data
    //    rec = int_array;
    rec = int_map;
    //    rec = int_a_union_datum;

    //print data detail
    sout("");
    char * json;
    sout("rec:");
    avro_datum_to_json(rec, 0, &json);
    sout(json);

    //serialize
    char buf[1024];
    avro_writer_t writer = avro_writer_memory(buf, 1024);
    res = avro_write_data(writer, schema, rec);
    if (res) {
        psout("write result", avro_strerror());
    }
    long len = avro_size_data(writer, schema, rec);
    piout("data len", len);

    //read
    avro_reader_t reader = avro_reader_memory(buf, 1024);
    avro_datum_t rslt;
    res = avro_read_data(reader, schema, schema, &rslt);
    if (res) {
        psout("read error ", avro_strerror());
    }

    //read data
    sout("");
    sout("rslt:");
    avro_datum_to_json(rslt, 0, &json);
    sout(json);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my target schema:    **avro_schema_t schema**;
and this is my data:    **avro_datum_t rec**;

in `//choose schema` and `//choose data` part,

if `schema = int_array_schema` and `rec = int_array`,
the output is like this:
[int_arry_schema output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RBME.png)

if `schema = int_map_schema` and `rec = int_map`,
the output is like this:
[int_map_schema output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Mcn.png)

**Segmentation fault** appears here: `res = avro_write_data(writer, schema, rec);`.

so, how can i have a map with arrays as it's values?

Comment: Translate `必须用vprintf` into English.

Comment: that's not quite important, so i deleted it. i edited the format. is it better?@v7d8dpo4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be doing anything wrong in relation to the code; however it looks like since the project moved to the 'generic value' format and implemented the legacy wrappers for the new API it appears like this is a bug in backwards compatibility.

If you regenerate the schema from the json you built in your code, it works, which seems to indicate a functional regression:

so here, if we generate a new copy of the schema:

```
psout("schema", schemaPrintBuf);
avro_schema_t from_json;
if (!avro_schema_from_json_literal(schemaPrintBuf, &from_json)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert from json literal: %s", avro_strerror());
    exit(1);
}

// then in the write:
res = avro_write_data(writer, from_json, rec);
```

it no longer crashes - this is with only replacing that single schema reference - if you leave the other references to schema in the re-read it looks like it works.

Alternatively, because you constructed the `avro_datum_t` based on a known, manually constructed schema, you could disable the writer verification, which seems to be the origin of the crash:

```
 res = avro_write_data(writer, NULL, rec);
```

does not crash in this case - it may be some complication of the schema verification in this case.

Comment: it still crash when i user a json schema. but it works when i disable the writer verification!  thanks!